# Why am i getting "memory error" in reportlab while generating the pdf

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pdf, reportlab

I have been trying to generate a pdf using reportlab.
When i put 4 images, It works.
But I put just 5 images it shows memory error. 
Please help.

Here is the code:

```
def plot_graph():
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5.25))

    stats = data.resample('D', on='DATE').count()['DATE']
    stats.plot(figsize=(12, 12))
    plt.xlabel('Dates', fontsize=16)
    plt.ylabel('Number of People', fontsize=16)
    plt.grid()

    buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buf, format='png', dpi=300)
    buf.seek(0)

    return buf




def plot_graph1():
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5.25))

    stats = data.resample('D', on='DATE').count()['DATE']
    stats.plot(figsize=(12, 12))
    plt.xlabel('Dates', fontsize=16)
    plt.ylabel('Number of People', fontsize=16)
    plt.grid()

    buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buf, format='png', dpi=300)
    buf.seek(0)

    return buf1
```

Similarly for plot 2,3,4. This makes total 5 plots.

```
image_buffer1 = plot_graph()
im = Image(image_buffer1, 8 * inch, 5.25 * inch)
Story.append(im)

add_text("Description of the chart.")

image_buffer1 = plot_graph1()
im2 = Image(image_buffer2, 8 * inch, 5.25 * inch)
Story.append(im2)

add_text("Description of the chart.")
```

Similarly for plot 2,3,4. This makes total 5 plots.

Please help. 
What is wrong with my code?

error:

```
 name = _digester(rawdata+mdata)
MemoryError
```

Comment: Well the reason is obvious: at this point, your process already ate all available memory. Images can eat a lot of memory and PDFs too, and while generating the PDF you have all this _and much more_ loaded in memory, so you have to be very careful with how you use memory (make sure you free whatever you can, work from file instead of memory whenever possible etc).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Do you have any solution for this? detailed to procedure to execute it?

Comment: @renny the "procedure" is in all letters in my previous comment: "you have to be very careful with how you use memory (make sure you free whatever you can, work from file instead of memory whenever possible etc)". Note that even then there's _of course_ still the hard limit of your available memory.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason you are running out of memory is beacause you aren't closing your `plt`.

I use this function to save and draw my plots in my PDFs:

```
def save_and_draw(fig, x_img, y_img, width_img=width_img, height_img=height_img):

    imgdata = BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(imgdata, format="png")
    imgdata.seek(0)
    imgdata = ImageReader(imgdata)

    self.c.drawImage(imgdata, x_img, y_img, width_img, height_img)
    plt.close(fig)
```

Some of them have more than 15 plots and everything works fine for me. Hope it helps!

Comment: Please see the updated code. I used the same code with plt.close() and it does not work too. P.S - I also have same memory issue

Comment: There's no `plt.close()` in your code. And even if it had, you have to pass your figure to the `close()` function (look at my function: `plt.close(fig)`) or `all` to close all figures. Check [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.close.html).